# Why do I get this error when trying to constraint a PK in view in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I created a view that is required by a 3rd party company for creating a tool for us. They are saying that the `GET` call requires the view to have a `primary key`. The underlying table has a `PK` column called `IDFaktura`, but the view does not count this as a `PK`. So, I try to do the following:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_FAKTURA (extnr, nr, fakturadate,
 constraint view_FAKTURA_pk primary key (idfaktura) disable novalidate)
 AS SELECT idfaktura, extnr, nr, fakturadate FROM table_faktura WHERE
 fakturadate >= to_date('01.12.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy') AND fakturadate <
 to_date('31.12.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

`But get the error:  SQL Error: ORA-00904: "table_FAKTURA"."IDFAKTURA": invalid identifier 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"`

Why does it give me this error? From what I was able to find online it should work.

Comment: Please take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160182/oracle-create-a-view-with-a-primary-key

Comment: I looked at that but it says to use disabled. ANd I am using `disable novalidate`, but still get the error. Ive spent a long time looking at this thread but I see that I am using the same syntax. I tried with `rely` too before `disable novalidate`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining the PK on column `idfaktura`, but you aren't creating a column with that name. As you are selecting four columns in the view query you seem to have intended to have it there (rather than really wanting the PK on `extnr` say), so you just need to include it in the column list for the view itself:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW view_FAKTURA (idfaktura, extnr, nr, fakturadate,
-------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^
  constraint view_FAKTURA_pk primary key (idfaktura) disable novalidate) AS
SELECT idfaktura, extnr, nr, fakturadate
FROM table_faktura
WHERE fakturadate >= to_date('01.12.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
AND fakturadate < to_date('31.12.2019', 'dd.mm.yyyy');
```

Incidentally, you might find it a bit simpler to use date literals:

```
...
WHERE fakturadate >= DATE '2019-12-01'
AND fakturadate < DATE '2019-12-31';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=ab44a3ff8884d152bf00763f59f7426a)

And also if that is supposed to cover the entire month, you probably actually want:

```
...
WHERE fakturadate >= DATE '2019-12-01'
AND fakturadate < DATE '2020-01-01';
```

as your current range will exclude all data from December 31st. Which may be what you want, but of course, but looks unlikely.

Comment: Thank you. Something so obvious was hitting me in the face and I could not see it...